# How to post the status updates in the Status.Net in android using the yamba-8 tutorial

Tags: android, twitter

Actually, I am facing a problem in Android. I am creating an application that connects to a Twitter like app called Status.Net. I have created an account in this site with my own username and password. Now the application which I have created, connects to this Status.Net site. Originally, this android application was picked up from one of the learning android website called Learning Android by Marko Gargenta and I have downloaded the source code from its git. I am creating my own version of this application by specifying a different API root as farmnews.aaditech.com/api (originally the API root was http://yamba.marakana.com/api). The code with original API root was working fine. It updated the status in yamba.marakana.com and the status is shown in the timeline too. But when I specify my own API root, it just updates into the status.net and shows a toast message "Failed To Post" which should not be bcoz it is obviously posting on the status.net. I don't knw wht is the problem. But I know if I just change one line of the API root, everything will be working fine.

**YambaApplication.java**

```
package com.marakana.yamba8;

import java.util.List;

import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.Status;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class YambaApplication extends Application implements
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
private static final String TAG = YambaApplication.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String LOCATION_PROVIDER_NONE = "NONE";
public static final long INTERVAL_NEVER = 0;
public Twitter twitter;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private StatusData statusData;
private boolean serviceRunning;
private boolean inTimeline;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
this.prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
this.statusData = new StatusData(this);
Log.i(TAG, "Application started");
}

public synchronized Twitter getTwitter() {
 if (this.twitter == null) {
   String username = this.prefs.getString("username", null);
   String password = this.prefs.getString("password", null);
   //String url = this.prefs.getString("url",
   //  "http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
   String url = this.prefs.getString("url",
   "http://farmnews.aaditech.com/index.php/api"); //1
   //String url = this.prefs.getString("url",
   //"http://identi.ca/api");
   //String url = this.prefs.getString("url",
   //"http://farmnews.aaditech.com");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)
      && !TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
      this.twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
      this.twitter.setAPIRootUrl(url);
    }
  }
  return this.twitter;
}

 public boolean startOnBoot() {
   return this.prefs.getBoolean("startOnBoot", false);
 }

 public StatusData getStatusData() {
   return statusData;
 }

  public synchronized int fetchStatusUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching status updates");
    Twitter twitter = this.getTwitter();
    if (twitter == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Twitter connection info not initialized");
    return 0;
  }
  try {
    List<Status> statusUpdates = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
    long latestStatusCreatedAtTime = this.getStatusData()
      .getLatestStatusCreatedAtTime();
    int count = 0;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for (Status status : statusUpdates) {
      values.put(StatusData.C_ID, status.getId());
      long createdAt = status.getCreatedAt().getTime();
      values.put(StatusData.C_CREATED_AT, createdAt);
      values.put(StatusData.C_TEXT, status.getText());
      values.put(StatusData.C_USER, status.getUser().getName());
      Log.d(TAG, "Got update with id " + status.getId() + ". Saving");
      this.getStatusData().insertOrIgnore(values);
      if (latestStatusCreatedAtTime < createdAt) {
       count++;
      }
     }
    Log.d(TAG, count > 0 ? "Got " + count + " status updates"
      : "No new status updates");
    return count;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch status updates", e);
    return 0;
   }
 }

  public synchronized void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    this.twitter = null;
  }

  public boolean isServiceRunning() {
     return serviceRunning;
  }

  public void setServiceRunning(boolean serviceRunning) {
    this.serviceRunning = serviceRunning;
  }

  public boolean isInTimeline() {
     return inTimeline;
  }

  public void setInTimeline(boolean inTimeline) {
     this.inTimeline = inTimeline;
  }

  public String getProvider() {
     return prefs.getString("provider", LOCATION_PROVIDER_NONE);
  }

  public long getInterval() {
     // For some reason storing interval as long doesn't work
     return Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("interval", "0"));
  }

  @Override
  public void onTerminate() {
  super.onTerminate();
  this.statusData.close();
  Log.i(TAG, "Application terminated");
  }
}
```

**DDMS LogCat**

```
    10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844): Failed to fetch status updates
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844): winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: org.json.JSONException: No value for profile_background_color
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$User.<init>(Twitter.java:693)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$Status.<init>(Twitter.java:464)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$Status.getStatuses(Twitter.java:342)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getStatuses(Twitter.java:1691)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getFriendsTimeline(Twitter.java:1454)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at com.marakana.yamba8.YambaApplication.fetchStatusUpdates(YambaApplication.java:73)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at com.marakana.yamba8.UpdaterService.onHandleIntent(UpdaterService.java:35)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for profile_background_color
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$User.<init>(Twitter.java:660)
10-28 00:36:04.964: ERROR/YambaApplication(844):     ... 10 more
```

I tried using the other API root URL http://identi.ca/api but it does not seem to be working

Please help me out

Regards and Thanks
Sohaib Rahman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem, the identi.ca API doesn't appear to return values for:

profile_background_color
profile_link_color
profile_text_color
profile_sidebar_fill_color
profile_background_tile

But the customised JTwitter library supplied by the book's author expects the API to return values for them and when it doesn't find them, it throws a org.json.JSONException wrapped up in a winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException.

I've downloaded the source for the library from:

https://github.com/marakana/LearningAndroidYamba/tree/master/JTwitterYamba

and updated the library by commenting out the relevant lines for those items listed above. This has solved the problem for me.